# Multiple field's values being changed when one field's value is changed

Tags: c#, field

I have this code below:

```
public GameMenu(Scene startScene)
{
    this.StartSceneBackup = startScene;
    this.StartSceneBackup.Entities[0].X = 200;

    this.StartScene = startScene;
}
```

the StartSceneBackup variable is NEVER touched and only the StartScene variable is accessed, however when I change the value of X via `this.StartSceneBackup.Entities[0].X = 200;` it changes the value of `this.StartScene.Entities[0].X = 200;`

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because Scene is a reference type, StartSceneBackup and StartSceneBackup point to the same object.
About reference type ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx

EDIT

if you want save a backup copy, you should understand Shallow Clone and Deep Clone, for reference type u must use deep clone, u can implements ICloneable interface in Scene class like this

```
public class Scene : ICloneable
{
    /// your codes

    public object Clone()
    {
        // it is DEEP CLONE
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
            stream.Position = 0;
            return (Scene)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public GameMenu(Scene startScene)
{
this.StartSceneBackup = startScene.Clone();
...
```